# Why does javascript not allow an anonymous function with no assignment?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

"Unexpected Token (" Thrown from line 1. Why ?

```
function (a,b,c) {
        // code    
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a [function declaration and a function expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.5). What you have is a function declaration that is missing the mandatory name. In a function expression, the name is optional.

Comment: @RobG thanks to your wonderful answer, I now know the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Techfoobar is essentially correct, another way to explain it is that a *FunctionDeclaration* must have a name, whereas in a *FunctionExpression* the name is optional.

What is the difference between the two? A function declaration is any **statement** that starts with the reserved word `function`. So:

```
function foo() {}
```

is a function declaration.

A function expression is like a declaration but it appears anywhere in a statement **other than the start**, so:

```
(function (){});
var x = function(){};
if (6 != function(){return 'foo';}()){}
```

are all function expressions and do not need names.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is a syntax error. Your function has no name.

Your function either has to have a name if it is to be defined the way you've done.

To check this, paste your code in Firebug console and execute it. You'll get the error

> SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

You can correct it by giving your function a name.

For example:

```
function foo(blah) {
    ...
}
```

---

For anonymous functions defined in the global scope, you either need to assign it to something OR you need to immediately execute it.

i.e.

either

```
var x = function(blah) {
    ...
};
```

OR

```
(function(blah) {
    ...
})(arguments);
```

because otherwise there is absolutely no way they can be called.

Comment: Only defining it. The console is real handy for checking syntax.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow - I've expanded the answer to include some info about anonymous functions.

Comment: @techfoobar—+1 but unassigned anonymous functions in global code don't need to be immediately executed, though they're a bit useless if they aren't. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Missing name in function statement. check it with [`jslint`](http://www.jslint.com)

try

```
function tdip() {
    var ts = tdip.find('>span');
    var trap = [];
    ts.contents().each(

    function () {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.data.length > 0) {
                trap.push(this.data.trim());
            } else if ($(this).text && $(this).text().length > 0) {
                trap.push($(this).text().trim());
            }
        }
    });
    return trap.join('');
}
```

Comment: @Andy Ray what **eff** mean? i didn't get u

Comment: What do you mean `function tdip {` ? What syntax is that?

Comment: Sorry its Typo :- Thanks @techfoobar